# INSERT statement doesn't insert data into table

Tags: c#, sql-server

I have problem with an `INSERT` statement. I get data from gridviev and it works fine, but I can't insert them into table

```
private void button3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    int amorplanid = 0;
    int idn = 0;
    DateTime datum;
    double interest = 0;
    double principal = 0;
    double payment = 0;
    double newprincipal = 0;

    string nizz = "";
    string[] niz= new string[7];
    for (int x = 0; x < dataGridView1.Rows.Count-1; x++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < dataGridView1.Rows[x].Cells.Count; j++)
        {
            nizz += dataGridView1.Rows[x].Cells[j].Value.ToString()+"."; 
        }
        niz = nizz.Split('.');

        amorplanid = System.Convert.ToInt32(niz[0]);
        idn = System.Convert.ToInt32(niz[1]);
        // datum = System.Convert.ToDateTime(niz[2]);
        datum = DateTime.Now;
        interest = System.Convert.ToDouble(niz[3]);
        principal = System.Convert.ToDouble(niz[4]);
        payment = System.Convert.ToDouble(niz[5]);
        newprincipal = System.Convert.ToDouble(niz[6]);

        String insert = @"INSERT INTO AmortPlanCoupT(ID, AmortPlanID, CoupDate, Interest, Principal, Payxment, NewPrincipal) VALUES (" + idn + "," + amorplanid + "," + datum + "," + (float)interest + "," + (float)principal + "," + (float)payment + "," + (float)newprincipal + ")";
        SqlConnection myconn = new SqlConnection(conn);
        // String MyString = @"INSERT INTO Employee(ID, FirstName, LastName) VALUES(2, 'G', 'M')";
        try
        {
            myconn.Open();
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(insert, myconn);
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            myconn.Close();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString());
        }
    }

    label14.Text = niz[0];
}
```

I have created a Windows console app to test :

I have table `test` with two columns `id (int) , leto (float)`;

```
SqlConnection MyConnection = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\App_Data\Database1.mdf;Integrated Security=True;User Instance=True");

try
{
    MyConnection.Open();

    String MyString = @"INSERT INTO test(id, leto) VALUES(2, 2)";
    SqlCommand MyCmd = new SqlCommand(MyString, MyConnection);

    MyCmd.ExecuteScalar();
    MyConnection.Close();
}
catch (Exception e)
{
    Console.WriteLine(e.ToString());
}
```

I've been trying different stuff to write data to table, and just can't get them there.

Comment: You should **never** concatenate together a SQL statement - [use **parametrized queries** instead](http://www.csharp-station.com/Tutorials/AdoDotNet/Lesson06.aspx) - **always, no exceptions!**

Comment: user... did you by chance run SQL Profiler to make sure you're on the right connection,etc.?  I've done this sort of thing in the past, and wound up being connected to the wrong server.

Comment: @marc_s: There's an exception to every rule (including this one). But I do agree. This code is vulnerable to SQL injection.

Comment: Also stop using the user instances / attachDbFileName features. I bet you are looking at a different copy of the database than your application.

Comment: @KendallFrey: what valid exception do you see to this rule? Just curious ...

Comment: @marc_s: I don't know of one, but I'm guessing there is one, somewhere.

Comment: Hello..Im new to C# @ marc thanks for advice..iv tried with parametrized queries but it didnt work. @AAron Bertrand how can i change attachDBFileName. I have 2 diffrent projects and one database in both projects..how is possible to look at diffrent copy of databse ? Just like i said im new to c#

Answer (score 5):

As I've said before on this site - the whole *User Instance and AttachDbFileName=* approach is flawed - at best! Visual Studio will be copying around the `.mdf` file and **most likely**, your `INSERT` works just fine - but you're just looking at the **wrong .mdf file** in the end!

If you want to stick with this approach, then try putting a breakpoint on the `myConnection.Close()` call - and then inspect the `.mdf` file with SQL Server Mgmt Studio Express - I'm almost certain your data is there.

The **real solution** in my opinion would be to

1. install SQL Server Express (and you've already done that anyway)
2. install SQL Server Management Studio Express
3. create your database in **SSMS Express**, give it a logical name (e.g. `Database1`)
4. connect to it using its logical **database name** (given when you create it on the server) - and don't mess around with physical database files and user instances. In that case, your connection string would be something like:

   ```
   Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS;Database=Database1;Integrated Security=True
   ```

   and everything else is **exactly** the same as before...

Answer (score -2):

Before you go any further, you should rewrite your code to use parameters, instead of string concatenation.