# How to save data to Database

Tags: c#, sql-server-2008

I have searched and found out this code to save data to database, connection string is ok, and no exceptions/errors are thrown, but i dont know why this code is not saving data into my database..

```
    string query = "Insert Into BookConfiguration (BookNum, x_axis, y_axis, BookName) Values (@BookNum, @x_axis, @y_axis, @BookName)";
    string connStr = "Data Source=.\\SQLEXPRESS;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\\BookShelf.mdf;Integrated Security=True;User Instance=True";


    try
    {
        using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(connStr))
        {                   
                SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter();
                da.InsertCommand = new SqlCommand(query, conn);
                da.InsertCommand.Parameters.Add("@BookNum", SqlDbType.Int).Value = quantity;
                da.InsertCommand.Parameters.Add("@x_axis", SqlDbType.Int).Value = x;
                da.InsertCommand.Parameters.Add("@y_axis", SqlDbType.Int).Value = y;
                da.InsertCommand.Parameters.Add("@BookName", SqlDbType.Text).Value = openFileDialog1.FileName;
            conn.Open();    

            da.InsertCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();

            conn.Close();
        }
    }

    catch (SqlException ex)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Error Occured " + ex.Message);
    }
```

**EDIT** 
i have now changed the code same problem

code:

```
        try
        {
            using (TransactionScope scope = new TransactionScope())
            {

                using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(connStr))
                {
                    conn.Open();
                    using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(query, conn))
                    {
                        cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@BookNum", quantity));
                        cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@x_axis", x));
                        cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@y_axis", y));
                        cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@BookName", openFileDialog1.FileName));
                        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                    }
                    conn.Close();
        }

                scope.Complete();
            }
        }
```

i hope it is clear not vague...

coded in c# visual studio 2010 sql server 2008...

Comment: If there are no errors, my first guess would be that there is an implicit transaction and you aren't committing it.  Also, whats with the SqlDataAdapter?  Seems unnecessary - you should just be able to create an SqlCommand and use that directly.

Comment: i first used sqlcommand only same prob then tried sqlDataAdapter same i even tried Transactions but no luck..

Comment: How do you know the data isn't being added to the database?  Are you viewing the contents of `BookShelf.mdf` with a database explorer tool, or running a SELECT command somewhere else in your application?

Comment: whenever i execute this method by clicking on a button i check the table by VS db explorer tool..

Comment: Can you do line by line debugging to confirm the code does run and just after the after the conn.close() (use a break point), can you check the database and see the data? Also try switching on the SQL Profiler to see if the data is being sent to the write place.

Comment: @AaronLS while in debug mode i can see my x y quantity and openfi... have values and no error occurs while they get assign to table values

Comment: Stop using user instances + attachDbFileName!

Comment: @AaronLS i changed SQLexception to exception no error

Comment: possible duplicate of [INSERT statement doesn't insert data into table](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10739913/insert-statement-doesnt-insert-data-into-table)

Comment: @PreetSangha i did so,, made breakpoint after con.close() and check the table via vs database explorer,, no changes

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I can almost guarantee that because you are using the deprecated User Instances / AttachDbFileName features, that you are looking at a different copy of your database than your program is.

Please see the answer from @marc_s here for how to proceed:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/10740026/61305

Essentially, stop using this useless feature. Attach your database to a real instance of SQL Server, then your database is fixed, and you can connect to the same copy of it as your program...

Comment: this is little getting into my mind please give more explanation this could help me i will be very thankful

Comment: @user1415295 could you tell me which part is not clear? Did you read marc's answer?

Comment: could u explain briefly what this mean using the deprecated User Instances / AttachDbFileName features 
i am beginner

Comment: lol i didnt downvoted any answer i am checking the link thnks btw

Comment: It means this feature (where you are using "User Instances" in your connection string), which when combined with AttachDbFileName makes a distinct copy of the database for each user/program that uses it, will not be supported in the future. Deprecation was first announced when SQL Server 2008 was released: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms143729%28SQL.100%29.aspx ... in SQL Server 2012 you should be using SqlLocalDb for isolated development. I have a primer here: http://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/2694/getting-started-with-sql-server-2012-express-localdb/

Comment: well i am trying this but i havent created any db with same name before but my application and .mdf both have same name
do u think this could create problem??

Comment: thanks i figured out whats my problem is
i will report bck once i'll get success
thanks everyone God Bless You All Ameen

Comment: Thank you all i made another db with simple connection string

 string connStr = "Data Source=.\\SQLEXPRESS; Database = BookShelf2 ;Integrated Security=True;";

and it works data is being save into DB Thanks all specially @Aaron Bertrand